# Calculate hourly tide level

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MYSQL that contains the daily High/Low tide levels:

```
+-----+---------------------+------+---------+
| ID  | Date                | Feet | HighLow |
+-----+---------------------+------+---------+
| 960 | 2016-09-13 05:55:00 |  0.2 | L       |
| 961 | 2016-09-13 12:56:00 |  2.5 | H       |
| 962 | 2016-09-13 19:21:00 |  0.6 | L       |
| 963 | 2016-09-14 00:35:00 |  1.7 | H       |
+-----+---------------------+------+---------+
```

I would like to expand this table to include the approximate tide level for each hour of the day.  I have a query that gives me the number of hours (in decimal format) between tides, and the change in level (in feet):

```
select
  t.date,
  t.feet,
  t.highlow,
  time_to_sec(timediff(t.date, @lastdt )) / 3600 as 'dif',
  if(t.feet IS NOT NULL, t.feet - @lastft, 000 ) as 'ft',
  @lastdt := t.date,
  @lastft := t.feet

from
  tides t,
  ( select @lastdt := 0,
           @lastft := 0 ) SQLVars

order by
  t.date);
```

Which gives the result:

```
+---------------------+------+---------+--------+------+
| date                | feet | highlow | dif    | ft   |
+---------------------+------+---------+--------+------+
| 2016-09-13 05:55:00 |  0.2 | L       | 6.0333 | -1.2 |
| 2016-09-13 12:56:00 |  2.5 | H       | 7.0167 |  2.3 |
| 2016-09-13 19:21:00 |  0.6 | L       | 6.4167 | -1.9 |
| 2016-09-14 00:35:00 |  1.7 | H       | 5.2333 |  1.1 |
+---------------------+------+---------+--------+------+
```

I've been unable to figure out how to divide the tide drop amount(ft) by the number of hours between tides(dif) to get the hourly tide change; then add it in hourly increments.

An example of the output I'd like to see from the table above:
2.3 / 7.0 = .33 (feet per hour)

```
+---------------------+------+
| date                | feet |
+---------------------+------+
| 2016-09-13 05:55:00 |  0.2 |
| 2016-09-13 06:55:00 |  0.5 |
| 2016-09-13 07:55:00 |  0.8 |
| 2016-09-13 08:55:00 |  1.1 |
| 2016-09-13 09:55:00 |  1.4 |
| 2016-09-13 10:55:00 |  1.7 |
| 2016-09-13 11:55:00 |  2.0 |
| 2016-09-13 12:56:00 |  2.5 |
+---------------------+------+
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The height of the tide is a modified sinusoidal pattern, where the high tide moves around the clock in about 29 days, but the gap between high tide and low tide is not in general the same as the gap between low tide and high tide (see your example data).  There's a monthly cycle on the heights of the tides (neap tides and spring tides) too.  How accurately do you want to do your interpolation?  Linear interpolation is straight-forward by will not be all that accurate — but it might be sufficiently accurate.

Comment: Linear interpolation will be sufficient as this is just for estimating levels.  I don't anticipate significant drift over time because I will update the High/Low predictions from NOAA on a monthly basis.  Thank you!

Comment: Rephrasing your question, you want a SELECT statement that merges actual and calculated records (i.e. if you have one measurement at 00:00 and the next at 04:00, you want to _fabricate_ records for 01:00, 02:00 and 03:00, right?). I'm not sure how and if this can be done using a SELECT. It can be done, however, using some logic (e.g. Store Procedure).

Comment: Correct - filling the gaps between the already present measurements (high and low tides) is what I'm looking to do.  Also, it isn't critical that the spacing of fabricated records between the existing records be exact (e.g. existing high tide = 04:50, next record = 05:50, 06:50...).  Recording the estimated data on the hour (... next record = 06:00, 07:00, ...)  if using something like a numbers table or a row generator would be easier.

Comment: This seems like it would be simpler to solve in application level code. Do you even need to store the fake data?

Comment: No, it isn't necessary that I store the data - I just thought it would be easier to have a table with all the data pre-populated.  It would be fine if the application generated the estimated current tide when the user loads the page.